# Технологии для интернет-магазина Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хочу написать небольшой(300 единиц) интернет-магазин на Vue.js(Nuxt.js), back-end ,будет на C#.
Скажите, как лучше сбилдить проект на nuxt чтобы меньше было проблем при деплое сайта?

Comment: Вы еще даже ничего не написали, никакой проблемы не встретили, а уже решать проблемы какие то хотите. Решайте их по мере поступления, а наперёд их себе придумывать не нужно. У Nuxt нет никакой проблемы с билдом, темболее небольших приложений

Comment: Я не придумываю, я продумываю. Проблемы есть, особенно если это static. Поэтому и спрашиваю, в каком режиме луше собрать проект? PWA or SPA(universal)?

Comment: @ПоляковДенис вы четко понимаете разницу между PWA и SPA?

Answer (score 2):

Однозначно SPA+SSR, иначе поисковики не увидят сайта. Многие переходят на Nuxtjs именно потому, что там очень легко реализовать *Предобратку на стороне сервера*, или *Server Side Rendering (SSR)*.